# Is it possible to customize sub folders in Wordpress uploads?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I am currently setup a custom post type with a custom meta box for file uploading in posts. Based on [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/attaching-files-to-your-posts-using-wordpress-custom-meta-boxes-part-1--wp-22291), I am able to upload the file with `wp_upload_bits()` function, which is something like this:

```
 wp_upload_bits($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['tmp_name']));
```

The problem is that **I am unable to create the subfolders in uploads folder base on each custom post type automatically**. When the file is uploaded, it is either organized by years and months or dumped in `uploads` folder (if I go to Settings > Media and uncheck “Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders.)

---

### Notes

Based on [this article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/use-a-separate-upload-folder-for-custom-post-attachment-upload) about attachments in WordPress, it seems that one can work around this by bypassing Wordpress built-in API.

Is there any other ways for this?